Does simics support raptorlake?
I am new to simics simulator,
Because I just saw some model library like birch steam, I'd like to ask does simics also support raptor lake?
can you provide the command to run simics public version for raptor ROM file? thank you

Why was this tagged [tag:c]?

The public release of the Intel Simics simulator contains only the QSP-x86 and RISC-V-simple targets.  The QSP can be configured with modern processor cores, but it does not correspond to a modern platform such as Raptor Lake.  As such, it cannot run boot ROMs or UEFI from a real platform or board.
Other platforms are available to Intel customers under NDA, but not in the public release.

I am with the support team of Intel® Simics® simulator and we are not part of that kind of decision making. Sorry.
